# can time complexity of two code snippets be added?

Tags: time-complexity

Lets assume I have the following :

```
1- a code snippet "CODE1" with time complexity O(N^2)
2- a code snippet "CODE2" with time complexity O(L*N)
```

if I integrate both snippets in one java program like :

```
 public class Main {

 CODE1;

 CODE2;

 }
```

can I say that the complexity of this program is O(N^2 + L*N) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if N depends on the same input

Answer (score 1):

The complexity will be O(N^2), since it is the major term